# Sort array of hashes based on two properties

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes which I'd like to sort by one of the values. However, if two hashes have the same value if like to sort them on a second (backup) value.

In the example below I'd like to sort the hashes based of the value of "a". If two elements have the same value for "a" I'd like to sort by the value of "b" as a backup.

```
# Notice the first and last hashes have the same value for "a"
hashes = [
  {a: 2, b: 7},
  {a: 1, b: 0},
  {a: 9, b: 6},
  {a: 2, b: 8}
]
```

**Output**

```
{a: 1, b: 0},
{a: 2, b: 7},
{a: 2, b: 8},
{a: 9, b: 6}
```

Comment: Can you please give more details, Code you tried so far, array & expected o/p?

Comment: Please share an example of your code or structure you are working on. Your question hasn't enough information.

Comment: @GTA.sprx : I still don't see in your question any code which you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question does not show any attempt by the OP to solve his problem.

Comment: @user1934428, a question can be closed because it is a duplicate, it "needs details or clarity", it "needs more focus" or is "off-topic" ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)). Criteria for a question being "off-topic" is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Are you assuming this is a homework question? If not, what is your basis for voting to close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is pretty easy with using of [`#sort_by`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by) with [`#values_at`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/values_at)

```rb
hashes.sort_by { |e| e.values_at(:a, :b) }
=> [{:a=>1, :b=>0},
    {:a=>2, :b=>7},
    {:a=>2, :b=>8},
    {:a=>9, :b=>6}]
```

it also might be expanded, for example, you have array of hashes with 3 keys:

```
hashes = [
  {a: 2, b: 7, c: 8},
  {a: 1, b: 0, c: 5},
  {a: 9, b: 6, c: 6},
  {a: 2, b: 7, c: 3}
]
```

then:

```rb
hashes.sort_by { |e| e.values_at(:a, :b, :c) }

=> [{:a=>1, :b=>0, :c=>5},
    {:a=>2, :b=>7, :c=>3},
    {:a=>2, :b=>7, :c=>8},
    {:a=>9, :b=>6, :c=>6}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
hashes.sort { |hash1, hash2| [hash1[:a], hash1[:b]] <=> [hash2[:a], hash2[:b]]}
```