# How to sort an array of hashes with multiple values?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes which contains an `id` field and a `weight` field. I am able to sort it based on `weight` but I also need to make sure that the `id` field is sorted if there are duplicate weights. Below is the code snippet for reference.

```
# Input
arr = [{"id" => 10, "weight" => 23}, {"id" => 6, "weight" => 43}, {"id" => 12, "weight" => 5}, {"id" => 15, "weight" => 30}, {"id" => 11, "weight" => 5}]

arr.sort_by{|k| k["weight"]}

# Output: [{"id"=>12, "weight"=>5}, {"id"=>11, "weight"=>5}, {"id"=>10, "weight"=>23}, {"id"=>15, "weight"=>30}, {"id"=>6, "weight"=>43}]

# Expected output = [{"id"=>11, "weight"=>5}, {"id"=>12, "weight"=>5}, {"id"=>10, "weight"=>23}, {"id"=>15, "weight"=>30}, {"id"=>6, "weight"=>43}]
```

In the above example, `id = 12` and `id = 11` have the duplicate values. I need to have `id = 11` before `id = 12` in the array. I really appreciate some guidance on this. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of hashes based on two properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63987833/sort-array-of-hashes-based-on-two-properties)

Comment: If you found either answer helpful you should select the one you preferred.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Enumerable#sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) with an array too. Note the order of the values in the array.

```
arr.sort_by {|k| k.values_at("weight", "id") }
```

Quote from the docs of [`Array#<=>`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) about how comparison of array works:

> Arrays are compared in an “element-wise” manner; the first element of `ary` is compared with the first one of `other_ary` using the `<=>` operator, then each of the second elements, etc… As soon as the result of any such comparison is non zero (i.e. the two corresponding elements are not equal), that result is returned for the whole array comparison.

Comment: Just a note that here `sort_by` uses [Array<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) to order arrays. The third paragraph of the doc explains how that is done.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for referring to third paragraph of the documentation. That was good to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array#sort](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/sort) with the [spaceship operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827649/what-is-the-ruby-spaceship-operator) like so:

```
arr.sort do |a,b|
  if a["weight"] == b["weight"]
    a["id"] <=> b["id"]
  else
    a["weight"] <=> b["weight"]
  end
end
```